# barchart with categories and each category should have different color using jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart, bar-chart

I want to plot barchart with different category. each category in graph should be represented with different color.

below is my code:

```
JFreeChart chart = 
         ChartFactory.createBarChart("Comparison between the average of 2 values",
         XAXIS_NAME, YAXIS_NAME, dataSet, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true,
         false);    


    final CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);       
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
    BarRenderer renderer=new BarRenderer();

  System.out.print( "set the range axis to display integers only...");
    final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
    rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());

      System.out.print( "disable bar outlines...");
    renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
    renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);
    renderer.setMaximumBarWidth(0.10);


      System.out.print( "set up gradient paints for series...");
final GradientPaint gp0 = new GradientPaint(
        0.0f, 0.0f, Color.blue, 
        0.0f, 0.0f, Color.lightGray
    );
    final GradientPaint gp1 = new GradientPaint(
        0.0f, 0.0f, Color.green, 
        0.0f, 0.0f, Color.lightGray
    );

    renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, gp0);
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, gp1);
```

Comment: It seems this example is what you want:http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartBarChartDemo3differentcolorswithinaseries.htm

Comment: Or [`BarChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html#line.65), seen [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/images/BarRendererSample.png).

Comment: i got the solution for this problem.